# css-class in typo3 menu as sys_categories

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I would add by typoscript a CSS class to a menu item. It should stand as a class, the category of the page. How can I do that?

```
MAIN_NAV.1.NO = 1
    MAIN_NAV.1.NO {

        linkWrap = <h4>|</h4>
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="section **{field:sys_categories.title}**">|</li>||<li class="section">|</li>||<li class="section">|</li>||<li class="section">|</li>
        wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a category title/String with CONTENT Object.

```
NO {
            wrapItemAndSub.override.cObject = COA
            wrapItemAndSub.override.cObject {
                if {
                    isTrue.field = categories
                }
                5 = TEXT
                5.value = <div class="item
                10 = CONTENT
                10 {
                    table = pages
                    select {
                        pidInList.field = pid
                        uidInList.field = uid
                        join = sys_category_record_mm ON pages.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign JOIN sys_category ON sys_category.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local
                        where = 1
                        orderBy = sys_category.sorting
                    }
                    renderObj = TEXT
                    renderObj {
                        field = title
                    }
                }


                5000 = TEXT
                5000.value = ">|</div>
            }


        }
```